# How do disable SSLv3 in Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, ssl, httpclient

With reference to the POODLE vulnerability, i need to force my code to use **ONLY TLSv1** and **NOT SSLv3**.  I have set the **sslProtocols="TLSv1"** in my server.xml file, and set the system property "https.protocols" to "TLSv1".  Though this works with the connections created using HttpsUrlConnection, this doesnt solve the connections created using **org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient**

Java version is 1.5+

**My Sample code is as follows**

**Connection initiation**

```
MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager httpConnectionManager = new MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager();
connParams = httpConnectionManager.getParams();
connParams.setDefaultMaxConnectionsPerHost(10);
connParams.setMaxTotalConnections(75);
connParams.setConnectionTimeout(1000);
connParams.setSoTimeout(30000);
httpConnectionManager.setParams(connParams);
clientParams = new HttpClientParams();
clientParams.setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler(0, true));

try{
    Protocol customHttps = new Protocol("https", new EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory(), 443); 
    Protocol.registerProtocol("https",customHttps); //No I18N
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

httpClient = new org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient(clientParams, httpConnectionManager);
```

URL Calling

```
HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(url);
client.executeMethod(method);
Properties serviceData = new Properties();
serviceData.load(method.getResponseBodyAsStream());
```

**Error received**

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:174)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:136)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1720)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:954)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1138)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:632)
```

Any help to solve this is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

--N.Shankar

Comment: How have you fixed it?