# Android 4.4.2 SSL handshake aborted

Tags: java, android, ssl

Code works on my Genymotion Android 4.4.4 emulator but not on the device i'm using (4.4.2).

I've tried lots of "trust all certificate" workarounds but to no avail (I don't think this is the issue anyway, as the certificate is AOK).

I think I have identified the cipher (using a wireshark trace from my desktop); TLS 0x00 0x1E which appears to be somewhat rare?

Any idea how to fix?

Here's my code

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();
String baseURL = "https://mysite.co.uk/api/";
HttpGetHC4 request = new HttpGetHC4(baseURL + "/authenticate?user=abcd&password=1234");
CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

And error;

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x6abff398: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
 error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x684dfce0:0x00000000)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:449)
     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:340)
     at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:281)
     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:124)
     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(BasicHttpClientConnectionManager.java:322)
     at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:373)
     at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:225)
     at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
     at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
     at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
     at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:178)
     at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
     at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
     at com.example.lee.printticket.Main$OrderAsyncTask.onPostExecute(Main.java:239)
     at com.example.lee.printticket.Main$OrderAsyncTask.onPostExecute(Main.java:189)
     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x6abff398: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
 error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x684dfce0:0x00000000)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:406)
    ... 25 more
```

*EDIT*

Trying using a different technique/library;

```
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url ="https://mysite.co.uk/api/authenticate?user=abcd&password=1234";

        // Request a string response from the provided URL.
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                        Log.d("response: ", response);
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("response: ", error.toString());
            }
        });
        // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
        queue.add(stringRequest);
```

Returns;

```
D/response:: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x6ad51be0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
D/response:: error:140740B5:SSL routines:SSL23_CLIENT_HELLO:no ciphers available (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:486 0x684dfce0:0x00000000)
```

Or with the NoSSLv3SocketFactory hack from [Javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916962/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-javax-net-ssl-sslprotocolexception-ssl-han);

```
        HttpStack stack = new HurlStack(null, new NoSSLv3SocketFactory());
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this, stack);
```

Returns;

```
D/response:: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x6ae51d30: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
D/response:: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:744 0x684dfce0:0x00000000)
```

Comment: I guess You searched a lot for the problem, but have You seen this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29916962/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-javax-net-ssl-sslprotocolexception-ssl-han

Comment: I did, however I can't seem to figure how to apply the NoSSLv3SocketFactory to CloseableHttpClient. If I try something like `SSLSocketFactory nosslv3 = new NoSSLv3SocketFactory(sslc.getSocketFactory()); CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().setSSLSocketFactory(nosslv3).build();` I get `setSSLSocketFactory (org.apache.http.conn.socket.LayeredConnectionSocketFactory in HttpClientBuilder cannot be applied to javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory`

Comment: 0x00,0x1E is TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA and would be indeed very rare and also very insecure. I doubt that this cipher would work with Android 4.4.4. Instead I would assume problems with Server Name Indication but more can only be said if one knows more about the target site. Check [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) for problems related to specific Android versions or if the site requires SNI.

Comment: Plugging the site in didn't return anything strange that I could see. Appears to support TLS 1.0, TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2. Under handshake simulation it suggests TLS 1.2 w/ ciper; TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA   for android 4.4.2?

Comment: I have now confirmed the device doesn't allow SSLv3. But this still doesn't explain why I can't get it working using TLS.

Comment: I'm now led to believe none of the ciphers supported by the site are supported by the device. It would be great to find a way for java to explicitly state this? At the moment as I work around I have had to create a http->https apache proxy

Comment: if You find an answer, You should post it. That´s an interesting question and I will follow it.

Comment: I'm having similar issue. The Android version is 4.4.4. The server is full http2 with TLS 1.2.

Comment: I am getting same problem in Samsung galaxy note 2, OS 4.4.2.  It would be great if any one can help ?

Answer (score 10):

Android uses different protocols for network operations.

Default configuration for different Android versions.

I found solution for OkHttpClient.

```
Protocol    Supported (API Levels)  Enabled by default (API Levels)

SSLv3       1–25                    1–22
TLSv1       1+                      1+
TLSv1.1     16+                     20+
TLSv1.2     16+                     20+
```

So we have to change Protocol for connection in Android VERSION >= 16 & VERSION < 22.

Create java file **Tls12SocketFactory.java**

```
/**
 * Enables TLS v1.2 when creating SSLSockets.
 * <p/>
 * For some reason, android supports TLS v1.2 from API 16, but enables it by
 * default only from API 20.
 * @link https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocket.html
 * @see SSLSocketFactory
 */
public class Tls12SocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    private static final String[] TLS_V12_ONLY = {"TLSv1.2"};

    final SSLSocketFactory delegate;

    public Tls12SocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory base) {
        this.delegate = base;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return delegate.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return patch(delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return patch(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return patch(delegate.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return patch(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return patch(delegate.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private Socket patch(Socket s) {
        if (s instanceof SSLSocket) {
            ((SSLSocket) s).setEnabledProtocols(TLS_V12_ONLY);
        }
        return s;
    }
}
```

Put this method some where in your code.

```
public static OkHttpClient.Builder enableTls12OnPreLollipop(OkHttpClient.Builder client) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 22) {
            try {
                SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
                sc.init(null, null, null);
                client.sslSocketFactory(new Tls12SocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory()));

                ConnectionSpec cs = new ConnectionSpec.Builder(ConnectionSpec.MODERN_TLS)
                        .tlsVersions(TlsVersion.TLS_1_2).build();

                List<ConnectionSpec> specs = new ArrayList<>();
                specs.add(cs);
                specs.add(ConnectionSpec.COMPATIBLE_TLS);
                specs.add(ConnectionSpec.CLEARTEXT);

                client.connectionSpecs(specs);
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                Log.e("OkHttpTLSCompat", "Error while setting TLS 1.2", exc);
            }
        }

        return client;
    }

    public OkHttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().followRedirects(true).followSslRedirects(true)
                .retryOnConnectionFailure(true).cache(null).connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        return enableTls12OnPreLollipop(client).build();
    }
```

Create OkHttp instance like below :

```
private OkHttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .followRedirects(true)
            .followSslRedirects(true)
            .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
            .cache(null)
            .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    return enableTls12OnPreLollipop(client).build();
}
```

Use client object like this:

```
OkHttpClient client = getNewHttpClient();
Request.Builder requestBuilder = new Request.Builder();
URL url = new URL("YOUR_URL_LINK");
Request request = requestBuilder.url(url).build();
Call call = client.newCall(request);
Response response = call.execute();
```

[**THANKS**](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2372#issuecomment-244807676)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class ClientSSLSocketFactory {

    public static SSLSocketFactory getSocketFactory(Context context) {
        try {
            X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager() {
                public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] xcs, String string) throws CertificateException {
                }

                public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                    return new X509Certificate[0];
                }
            };
            SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            ctx.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, new SecureRandom());

            SSLSocketFactory ssf = SSLCertificateSocketFactory.getDefault(10000, new SSLSessionCache(context));
            return ssf;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ssl", "Error during the getSocketFactory");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And when creating the queue:

```
sRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, new HurlStack(null, ClientSSLSocketFactory.getSocketFactory()));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is SSL v3 based on strings like this suggesting that it is attempting to use SSL v3: SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3

SSL v3 is considered insecure and thus disabled on most modern software (even in places where you would otherwise expect it to work, many companies have simply yanked it out).  I also see from the stack trace that the code uses apache http client:
org.apache.http.impl.client

So you have to somehow prevent that apache http client from using ssl v3.  Apache http client exists separately from the standard Java SSL/TLS libraries.

There is another stackoverflow question that received no answers:
[How do disable SSLv3 in Apache HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27499233/how-do-disable-sslv3-in-apache-httpclient)

This link looks most promising:
https://discretemkt.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/commons-httpclient-can-disable-sslv3/

In there, the key line is

```
Protocol.registerProtocol(scheme, customHttps);
```

That call appears to allow you to bypass the existing ssl factory.  If you run that code first it may work, assuming the apache http client versions are compatible.

Also note that TLS 1.0 is also considered insecure these days.  TLS 1.2 and 1.3 and the standard now.